# partitioning big table with equal amount of lookup in primary key and a secondary key

Tags: mysql, partitioning

Im having a table with around 15.000.000 entries, its getting bigger, and Im starting to get "lock wait timeouts", because of its size. So Im looking into partitioning.

Lets say the table is a student/school database. Equal amount of lookups on school_id and student_id, student_id is primary key.

What mysql partitioning would be the best option? If I only do by key, I will have, for example 10 tables to look up, whenever I search for school_id?

Answer (score 0):

No, `PARTITIONing` does not intrinsically provide any performance gain.

MySQL rarely uses more than one index in a query.  Often a "composite" index is beneficial.

Let's see

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
The queries that are getting timeouts.
```

Comment: Hey. The table is optimized as much as possible. (Our server is getting 7000 requests per second, so anything not using an index optimal will just make it all crash). The table though, is getting up at around 10gb last time I check, which does something weird with filesize (its innodb in one table per file) in Linux. :)

Comment: "something weird with filesize"?  Show us `SHOW TABLE STATUS`

Comment: players
engine: InnoDB
version: 10
row_format: Compact
rows: 14720530
avg row length: 194
Data length: 2865774592
Max data length: 0
Index Length: 1275691008
Data free: 368050176
Auto increment: 191931364
Create time: 2014-04-05 05:24:55
Update: NULL
Check: NULL
Collation: utf8_unicode_ci
Checksum: NULL

Comment: Is the `.ibd` file about 4.4GB?  Are you doing lots of `DELETEs` (or `REPLACEs`) -- I see (1) lots of Data_free, and Auto_increment a lot bigger than `Rows`?

Comment: To address any of your other questions, I _really_ need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the queries.

Comment: We clean it up every 28 days. Thats our only option. It does have a lot of everything, and its a somewhat central table in our app.

Comment: I see no "composite" keys.  Let's see some of the slower/common queries.

Comment: How do you "clean it up"?  It looks like you have thrown away lots of `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids over time.  Are you using `REPLACE`?  Or do you reload the data monthly?

Comment: I have thrown a lot of keys away over time, since they are used in other tables as well. There are no slow queries, simply a "SELECT * FROM players WHERE id=1" can have the status "table lock" on it, which is weird, since I did not know innodb tables locked at table levels. (We are not using transactions or anything of the kind).